# Creating a graph from Neo4j Data in R

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

I have a dataset which consists of Users and Repositories, which I query against Neo4j

```
query = "
MATCH (user:User{name:'mattt'})-->(repo)
MATCH (repo)<--(allUsers:User)
RETURN repo.name, COLLECT(DISTINCT allUsers.name) AS users;
"
q = cypher(neo4j, query)
```

[image]

The relation is between the repo.name and a list of users point to it.

I am having trouble figuring out how to restructure the data to plot this in a graph.

Comment: What kind of graph? A graph with nodes and edges or something like a bar chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a Cypher query that returns an edgelist, rather than having a list of all users that given user points to. Something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)-->(r:Repo)
RETURN u.name AS from, r.name AS to;
```

Following along from [this blog post](http://neo4j.com/blog/visualize-graph-with-rneo4j/) about network visualization using RNeo4j:

```
query = "
MATCH (u:User)-->(r:Repo)
RETURN u.name AS from, r.name AS to;
"

edges = cypher(neo4j, query)
```

Then define a DataFrame for the nodes:

```
nodes = data.frame(id=unique(c(edges$from, edges$to)))
nodes$label = nodes$id
```

Then to visualize using the [visNetwork libary](http://dataknowledge.github.io/visNetwork/):

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```